# Is it possible to vectorize non-trivial loop in C with SIMD? (multiple length 5 double-precision dot products reusing one input)

Tags: arrays, c, performance, vectorization, simd

I have a performance critical **C** code where > 90% of the time is spent doing one basic operation:

[image: Operation]

The **C** code I am using is:

```C
static void function(double *X1, double *Y1, double *X2, double *Y2, double *output) {
    double Z1, Z2;
    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < 25; j++) { // sweep Y
        Z1 = 0;
        Z2 = 0;
        for (k = 0; k < 5; k++, i++) { // sweep X
            Z1 += X1[k] * Y1[i];
            Z2 += X2[k] * Y2[i];
        }
        output[j] = Z1*Z2;
    }
}
```

The lengths are fixed (X is 5; Y is 25; the output is 5). I have tried everything I know to make this faster. When I compile this code using clang with `-O3 -march=native -Rpass-analysis=loop-vectorize -Rpass=loop-vectorize -Rpass-missed=loop-vectorize`, I get this message:

> remark: the cost-model indicates that vectorization is not beneficial [-Rpass-missed=loop-vectorize]

But I assume the way to make this faster is with SIMD somehow. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Which SIMD instruction set are you targeting? Also, while that looks possible, it also looks really annoying.

Comment: I can use SSE3, SSE4.1, or AVX2.

Comment: If none of the arrays will ever overlap, adding `restrict` qualifiers might help the compiler.

Comment: Playing with OpenMP simd hinting is also a possibility.

Comment: Can this be done for multiple X's at once? I haven't worked it out but something like that would probably be useful. 5 is a really awkward size.

Comment: The issue is that the next X is dependent on the prior output, so they have to be sequential.

Comment: @Shawn - I am using OpenMP (v2018), but I couldn't figure out how to hint my way into SIMD, even after reading [the manual](https://info.ornl.gov/sites/publications/files/Pub69214.pdf).

Comment: Maybe try adding `#pragma omp simd` before the right for loop you're trying to optimize. Use `objdump` or similar tools to inspect the compiled binary to check if SIMD instructions are used.

Comment: What is `arch-native` in your case? (Do you have just SSE2, or also AVX/FMA?)

Comment: Is the next Y also dependent on the prior output, and could its layout be changed?

Comment: Btw: If you just replace `i` by `k+5*j` it is more evident, that this is essentially the element-wise product of two matrix-vector-products. Also, adding `-ffast-math` (probably just `-fassociative-math`) may give the compiler more options to optimize.

Comment: Are you saying that either X1 or X2 aliases output?

Comment: `Y2[i]` -> `*Y2++` and remove `i`.

Comment: In particular,  `#pragma omp simd reduction(+:Z1,Z2)`

Comment: I tried these suggestions:
(1) I added ```-ffast-math``` = **no difference** on my machine.
(2) I replaced ```Y2[i]``` with ```*Y2++``` (same for Y1) and removed ```i``` = 1.2x time (=> **slower**).
(3) I added ```#pragma omp simd reduction(+:Z1,Z2)```. This gave the error, "error: initialization clause of OpenMP for loop is not in canonical form ('var = init' or 'T var = init')". So I used the version without i (only j from (2) above). This yielded vectorized code "remark: vectorized loop (vectorization width: 4, interleaved count: 1) [-Rpass=loop-vectorize]" = 1.2x time (=> **slower**).

Comment: Are `Y1`, `Y2` fixed? Can you transpose them (outside the hot loop)? And how do `X1, X2` depend on the previous `output`?

Comment: ```Y1``` and ```Y2``` could potentially be transposed if this would significantly help somehow. The ```output``` might become an ```X``` in future function calls. There might be some gains to be had outside this function, although I was mainly interested in how to improve the function itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the extended discussions in the comments it looks like mostly you are interested in reducing the latency between reading `X1`, `X2` and writing `output`. What you are calculating is the element-wise product of two matrix-vector products. The two MV products can happen quasi-parallel (with OOO-excecution), but both MV products require the sum of five products, which you can do either in a sequence (as you are doing at the moment) or in a tree-like reduction:

```
Z = ((X[0]*Y[0] + X[1]*Y[1]) + X[2]*Y[2])  +  ([X[3]*Y[3] + [X[4]*Y[4]);
```

This results in a critical path of `mulsd` - `fmaddsd` - `fmaddsd` - `addsd`, which is followed by a multiplication of `Z1*Z2`. That means, assuming 4 cycles latency per FLOP, you'll have a latency of 20 cycles plus latency of reading and writing memory (unless you are able to keep everything in registers -- this requires you to show the surounding code). If you accumulate the values linearily, you'll have a critical path of `mulsd` - `fmaddsd` - `fmaddsd` - `fmaddsd` - `fmaddsd` - `mulsd` (i.e. 24 cycles + read/write)

Now if you are able to change the memory order of `Y`, it would be beneficial to transpose these matrices, because then you can easily calculate `output[0 ~ 3]` in parallel (assuming you have AVX), by first broadcast-loading each entry of `X` and doing packed accumulation.

```
void function_fma( const double* X1, const double* Y1, const double* X2, const double* Y2, double* output )
{
    // Load X1 and X2 vectors into 10 registers.
    const __m256d x1_0 = _mm256_broadcast_sd( X1 );
    const __m256d x1_1 = _mm256_broadcast_sd( X1 + 1 );
    const __m256d x1_2 = _mm256_broadcast_sd( X1 + 2 );
    const __m256d x1_3 = _mm256_broadcast_sd( X1 + 3 );
    const __m256d x1_4 = _mm256_broadcast_sd( X1 + 4 );

    const __m256d x2_0 = _mm256_broadcast_sd( X2 );
    const __m256d x2_1 = _mm256_broadcast_sd( X2 + 1 );
    const __m256d x2_2 = _mm256_broadcast_sd( X2 + 2 );
    const __m256d x2_3 = _mm256_broadcast_sd( X2 + 3 );
    const __m256d x2_4 = _mm256_broadcast_sd( X2 + 4 );

    // first four values:
    {
        // Multiply column 0
        __m256d z1 = _mm256_mul_pd( x1_0, _mm256_loadu_pd( Y1 ) );
        __m256d z2 = _mm256_mul_pd( x2_0, _mm256_loadu_pd( Y2 ) );

        // Multiply + accumulate column 1 and column 2
        z1 = _mm256_fmadd_pd( x1_1, _mm256_loadu_pd( Y1 + 5 ), z1 );
        z2 = _mm256_fmadd_pd( x2_1, _mm256_loadu_pd( Y2 + 5 ), z2 );
        z1 = _mm256_fmadd_pd( x1_2, _mm256_loadu_pd( Y1 + 10 ), z1 );
        z2 = _mm256_fmadd_pd( x2_2, _mm256_loadu_pd( Y2 + 10 ), z2 );

        // Multiply column 3
        __m256d z1_ = _mm256_mul_pd( x1_3, _mm256_loadu_pd( Y1 + 15 ) );
        __m256d z2_ = _mm256_mul_pd( x2_3, _mm256_loadu_pd( Y2 + 15 ) );

        // Multiply + accumulate column 4
        z1_ = _mm256_fmadd_pd( x1_4, _mm256_loadu_pd( Y1 + 20 ), z1_ );
        z2_ = _mm256_fmadd_pd( x2_4, _mm256_loadu_pd( Y2 + 20 ), z2_ );

        // Add both partial sum
        z1 = _mm256_add_pd( z1, z1_ );
        z2 = _mm256_add_pd( z2, z2_ );

        // Multiply and store result
        _mm256_store_pd(output, _mm256_mul_pd(z1, z2));
    }
    // last value:
    {
        // Multiply column 0
        __m128d z1 = _mm_mul_sd( _mm256_castpd256_pd128(x1_0), _mm_load_sd( Y1 + 4) );
        __m128d z2 = _mm_mul_sd( _mm256_castpd256_pd128(x2_0), _mm_load_sd( Y2 + 4) );

        // Multiply + accumulate column 1 and column 2
        z1 = _mm_fmadd_sd( _mm256_castpd256_pd128(x1_1), _mm_load_sd( Y1 + 9 ), z1 );
        z2 = _mm_fmadd_sd( _mm256_castpd256_pd128(x2_1), _mm_load_sd( Y2 + 9 ), z2 );
        z1 = _mm_fmadd_sd( _mm256_castpd256_pd128(x1_2), _mm_load_sd( Y1 + 14 ), z1 );
        z2 = _mm_fmadd_sd( _mm256_castpd256_pd128(x2_2), _mm_load_sd( Y2 + 14 ), z2 );

        // Multiply column 3
        __m128d z1_ = _mm_mul_sd( _mm256_castpd256_pd128(x1_3), _mm_load_sd( Y1 + 19 ) );
        __m128d z2_ = _mm_mul_sd( _mm256_castpd256_pd128(x2_3), _mm_load_sd( Y2 + 19 ) );

        // Multiply + accumulate column 4
        z1_ = _mm_fmadd_sd( _mm256_castpd256_pd128(x1_4), _mm_load_sd( Y1 + 24 ), z1_ );
        z2_ = _mm_fmadd_sd( _mm256_castpd256_pd128(x2_4), _mm_load_sd( Y2 + 24 ), z2_ );

        // Add both partial sum
        z1 = _mm_add_sd( z1, z1_ );
        z2 = _mm_add_sd( z2, z2_ );

        // Multiply and store result
        _mm_store_sd(output+4, _mm_mul_sd(z1, z2));
    }
}
```

If you don't have FMA, you can replace these by multiplication and addition (this will not change the latency a lot, since only the additions are in the critical path -- throughput could be about 50% worse, of course). Also, if you don't have AVX, the first four values can be calculated by doing two times two values.

Comment: Clever idea to use the transpose this way. I used a slight variation of this suggestion and it took 0.7x time (**faster**).

Answer (score 3):

Try the following version, it requires SSE2 and FMA3. Untested.

```
void function_fma( const double* X1, const double* Y1, const double* X2, const double* Y2, double* output )
{
    // Load X1 and X2 vectors into 6 registers; the instruction set has 16 of them available, BTW.
    const __m128d x1_0 = _mm_loadu_pd( X1 );
    const __m128d x1_1 = _mm_loadu_pd( X1 + 2 );
    const __m128d x1_2 = _mm_load_sd( X1 + 4 );

    const __m128d x2_0 = _mm_loadu_pd( X2 );
    const __m128d x2_1 = _mm_loadu_pd( X2 + 2 );
    const __m128d x2_2 = _mm_load_sd( X2 + 4 );

    // 5 iterations of the outer loop
    const double* const y1End = Y1 + 25;
    while( Y1 < y1End )
    {
        // Multiply first 2 values
        __m128d z1 = _mm_mul_pd( x1_0, _mm_loadu_pd( Y1 ) );
        __m128d z2 = _mm_mul_pd( x2_0, _mm_loadu_pd( Y2 ) );

        // Multiply + accumulate next 2 values
        z1 = _mm_fmadd_pd( x1_1, _mm_loadu_pd( Y1 + 2 ), z1 );
        z2 = _mm_fmadd_pd( x2_1, _mm_loadu_pd( Y2 + 2 ), z2 );

        // Horizontal sum both vectors
        z1 = _mm_add_sd( z1, _mm_unpackhi_pd( z1, z1 ) );
        z2 = _mm_add_sd( z2, _mm_unpackhi_pd( z2, z2 ) );

        // Multiply + accumulate the last 5-th value
        z1 = _mm_fmadd_sd( x1_2, _mm_load_sd( Y1 + 4 ), z1 );
        z2 = _mm_fmadd_sd( x2_2, _mm_load_sd( Y2 + 4 ), z2 );

        // Advance Y pointers
        Y1 += 5;
        Y2 += 5;

        // Compute and store z1 * z2
        z1 = _mm_mul_sd( z1, z2 );
        _mm_store_sd( output, z1 );

        // Advance output pointer
        output++;
    }
}
```

It’s possible to micro-optimize further by using AVX, but I’m not sure it’s going to help much because the inner loop is too short. I think that these two extra FMA instructions are cheaper than the overhead of computing horizontal sum of the 32-byte AVX vectors.

**Update:** here's another version, it takes less instructions overall at the cost of a few shuffles. May of may not be faster for your use case. Requires SSE 4.1 but I think all CPUs which have FMA3 have SSE 4.1 as well.

```
void function_fma_v2( const double* X1, const double* Y1, const double* X2, const double* Y2, double* output )
{
    // Load X1 and X2 vectors into 5 registers
    const __m128d x1_0 = _mm_loadu_pd( X1 );
    const __m128d x1_1 = _mm_loadu_pd( X1 + 2 );
    __m128d xLast = _mm_load_sd( X1 + 4 );

    const __m128d x2_0 = _mm_loadu_pd( X2 );
    const __m128d x2_1 = _mm_loadu_pd( X2 + 2 );
    xLast = _mm_loadh_pd( xLast, X2 + 4 );

    // 5 iterations of the outer loop
    const double* const y1End = Y1 + 25;
    while( Y1 < y1End )
    {
        // Multiply first 2 values
        __m128d z1 = _mm_mul_pd( x1_0, _mm_loadu_pd( Y1 ) );
        __m128d z2 = _mm_mul_pd( x2_0, _mm_loadu_pd( Y2 ) );

        // Multiply + accumulate next 2 values
        z1 = _mm_fmadd_pd( x1_1, _mm_loadu_pd( Y1 + 2 ), z1 );
        z2 = _mm_fmadd_pd( x2_1, _mm_loadu_pd( Y2 + 2 ), z2 );

        // Horizontal sum both vectors while transposing
        __m128d res = _mm_shuffle_pd( z1, z2, _MM_SHUFFLE2( 0, 1 ) );   // [ z1.y, z2.x ]
        // On Intel CPUs that blend SSE4 instruction doesn't use shuffle port,
        // throughput is 3x better than shuffle or unpack. On AMD they're equal.
        res = _mm_add_pd( res, _mm_blend_pd( z1, z2, 0b10 ) );  // [ z1.x + z1.y, z2.x + z2.y ]

        // Load the last 5-th Y values into a single vector
        __m128d yLast = _mm_load_sd( Y1 + 4 );
        yLast = _mm_loadh_pd( yLast, Y2 + 4 );

        // Advance Y pointers
        Y1 += 5;
        Y2 += 5;

        // Multiply + accumulate the last 5-th value
        res = _mm_fmadd_pd( xLast, yLast, res );

        // Compute and store z1 * z2
        res = _mm_mul_sd( res, _mm_unpackhi_pd( res, res ) );
        _mm_store_sd( output, res );
        // Advance output pointer
        output++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, and I tried AVX, and in terms of throughput it's the usual: just under 2x improvement for this, about 3.5x improvement for AVX. But when the next X depends on the output, that all breaks down and they all take almost the same time. The versions with SIMD are still a bit faster, but not a lot.

Comment: @harold Are you saying your X and output pointers overlap? If some of these pointers overlap, the optimal implementation depends hugely on the surroundings code, which is missing from the question.

Comment: No pointer overlap, that would annoying in additional ways, but just writing the result back over X (*after* computing it), to "tie the ends together". Probably OP has some more logic in between, but I measured it that way because he said "next X is dependent on the prior output".

Comment: @harold If next X depends on previous output, the prototype of that function is probably less than ideal. In this case, OP better keep intermediate state in vector registers (with AVX, 2 SIMD registers is enough for a 5 elements FP64 vector), instead of marshalling that data through RAM back and forth all the time.

Comment: If so, keeping a transposed version of the 5x5 flatten matrix `Y1` and `Y2` in SIMD registers is certainly much better since it avoid horizontal sums.

Comment: This code took 0.87x time (**somewhat faster**). I will refactor the arrays a bit and see whether that helps even more.

Comment: @ErikWright See the update

Answer (score 1):

You can at least process 2 elements at a time by loading the lower and upper half registers separately. Unrolling `i` by two may give a small edge...

The `__restrict` keyword, if applicable, allows the five constant coefficients `X1[0..4], X2[0..4]` to be preloaded. If `X1` or `X2` partially alias output, it's better to let the compiler know it (by using the same array). In this way, as the complete function is unrolled, the compiler will not reload any element unnecessarily.

```
typedef double __attribute__((vector_size(16))) f2;

void function2(double *X1, double *Y1, double *X2, double *Y2, double *__restrict output) {
    double Z1, Z2;
    int i = 0, j, k;
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) { // sweep Y
        f2 Z12 = {0.0, 0.0};
        for (k = 0; k < 5; k++, i++) { 
            f2 Y12 = {Y1[i], Y2[i]};
            f2 X12 = {X1[k], X2[k]};
            Z12 += X12 * Y12;
        }
        output[j] = Z12[0]*Z12[1];
    }
}
```

If possible, please consider interleaving Y1Y2, X1X3:

```
void function2(f2 const *X12, f2 const *Y12, double *output) {
    int i = 0, j, k;
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) { // sweep Y
        f2 Z12 = X12[0] * Y12[0]; 
        for (k = 1; k < 5; k++, i++) { 
            Z12 += X12[k] * Y12[k];
        }
        output[j] = Z12[0]*Z12[1]; // possibly [j * 2]?
    }
}
```

Slightly better performance is probably available through intrinsics,  however, this answer emphasises auto-vectorisation.

Comment: It's usually sufficient to just `__restrict` the `output` variable.

Comment: That looks like C++ code. OP tagged their question C...

Comment: `restrict` is standardized in C though. No need for GNU extensions. However, const-qualifying the parameters like they should have been might achieve the same result.

Comment: Instead of starting with `0.0 += stuff` you could init Z12 with a product.  (Or compile with `-ffast-math` to keep the source simpler).  Without fast-math we can see GCC ( https://godbolt.org/z/hcMazTGzT ) do `addpd xmmX, xmm6` 5 times in the fully unrolled loop, where XMM6 was xor-zeroed.)  This depends on efficient `movhpd` for x86: On SKL / ICL it's single-uop but load micro-fused with a port-5 ALU shuffle, 1/clock.  Alder Lake E-cores, and AMD Zen, run it at 2/clock.

Comment: Or `-ffast-math` is indeed what I prefer when there's a possibility to let the compiler do the right thing from the simplest possible source code.

Comment: This code took 0.96x time (**slightly faster**) in my test. I am using clang, so I don't know whether GCC would give a better return.

Comment: Some source files shouldn't be compiled with `-ffast-math`; if your code depends on `-ffast-math` for full performance, it's maybe a good idea to make a note of it in a comment.

Comment: @ErikWright: What hardware are you testing on?  and clang version and options? `O3 -march=??`  This might be decent on AMD Zen where `movhpd` loads are 2/clock, unlike Intel where 1/clock `movhpd` makes this problematic.